# What is the difference between "accumulative" and "cumulative"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I'm having a hard time understanding the real distinction between [accumulative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accumulative) and [cumulative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cumulative).

**accumulative**

> *adjective*
>
> 1. tending to accumulate or arising from accumulation; cumulative.
> 2. tending to accumulate wealth; acquisitive.

**cumulative**

> adjective
>
> 1. increasing or growing by accumulation or successive additions: the cumulative effect of one rejection after another.
> 2. formed by or resulting from accumulation or the addition of successive parts or elements.
> 3. of or pertaining to interest or dividends that, if not paid when due, become a prior claim for payment in the future: cumulative preferred stocks.

These definitions (and those from other dictionaries as well) say different things but I can't understand how they aren't *really* meaning the same thing.

Yet, when thinking about it, it seems there are some cases where it is distinctly more correct to use one or the other.

**What's the difference, practically?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The big difference is that **cumulative** is *far more common* than **accumulative**.
[image: .]

At the level of actual meaning, to the extent that *accumulative* is used at all, it tends to refer to someone/something *doing the accumulating*. By contrast, *cumulative* is more associated with *that which is accumulated*.

If the sense intended is *acquisitive*, just use that word. In all other cases, use *cumulative*.

Answer (score 16):

*Accumulative* lays more emphasis on the process of accumulating, and *cumulative* on the result.  [Parallel to FumbleFingers' agent *vs.* substance distinction but perhaps an iota more transparent.]

Note that *[accumulative](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=accumula)* derives from *ad-* ("in addition") plus *[cumulare](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=cumula)*, "heap up", from *cumulus*, "heap".  As noted in [wiki.answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_definition_of_the_prefix_ac), prefix *ac* "replaces *ad* as a prefix when used in words where *ad* doesn't conjoin well with the root word *e.g.* acclaim, account, accomplice." (*Ac-* and *ad-* also are briefly mentioned in a useful chart of [Roots, Prefixes, Suffixes](http://www.ilbegypt.com/ilbdownloads/Root,%20Prefix%20or%20Suffix.pdf) pdf file.)  The 16th-century reasons for adding on adding on to adding on may be undiscoverable; of course the two words express minutely different meanings, but whether they express a difference worth expressing is far less clear.

In modern usage, there are numerous phrases (*cumulative distribution* in particular) where use of *accumulative* would appear illiterate; typically, one can avoid *accumulative* altogether.    Of course other forms of the word cannot be avoided, as in *accumulate wealth* and *accumulator register*.

(*Editing Note:* I removed an *either ... or* construction from the previous paragraph, in response to FumbleFingers' comment, based on my misunderstanding of "In all other cases, use cumulative".)

Comment: +1 for *agent vs. substance* - succinct way of putting it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the downvote is hard to figure.  Thanks for "the" edit

Answer (score 1):

Accumulative means having the characteristic of tending to accumulate.

Cumulative means having built up or accumulated over time. E.g. something has a cumulative effect, or is a cumulative result of something. It is more specific in meaning than 'accumulative', in that it is about a definite build up of one thing after another, as opposed to a general tendency to gather up.

There appears to be a tendency for people to use 'accumulative' incorrectly when they in fact mean 'a cumulative...'.

Hope that helps a bit!

Answer (score 1):

Without using forms of the words to define them (a linguistic no-no), "cumulative" increasing or increased in quantity, degree, or force by successive additions and "accumulative" means gathering or growing by gradual increases.